# Laravel 5.2 access example.com/ instead of example.com/public in shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel

so i want to upload my laravel project to shared hosting. After completing it, when i want to access my website (just call it www.example.com) it goes to /public directory and my solution is add route for /public as my homepage but i don't want it.

so here my website path

```
/
/laravel
/public_html
/tmp
```

here is my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

And here is my public_html/index.php

```
<?php

require __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/app.php';

$app->bind('path.public', function() {
return __DIR__;
});

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Comment: Your laravel files should live outside of public access. The laravel "public" folder can be anything, such as "public_html", as long as the public files are... public.

Comment: https://medium.com/laravel-news/the-simple-guide-to-deploy-laravel-5-application-on-shared-hosting-1a8d0aee923e - this link should help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should upload your your Laravel project to `public_html`  folder then add `.htaccess` file to root project

`.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: so put .htaccess to / folder and then upload all my laravel include 'public' folder to public_html? and one more, where should i put those code? after last </IfModule> in my .htaccess? or i replace all to this?

Comment: yes you need to upload all your project included  with `public` folder and then replace your `.htaccess`  in root project with answer code